# boot-clj: get rid of "version conflict detected"

Tags: clojure, boot-clj

boot-clj shows a lot of warnings about version conflicts on startup: They look like this:

```
Warning: version conflict detected: org.clojure/clojure version changes from 1.5.1 to 1.8.0
Warning: version conflict detected: clj-time version changes from 0.8.0 to 0.12.0
Warning: version conflict detected: riddley version changes from 0.1.7 to 0.1.12
Warning: version conflict detected: org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-utils version changes from 2.0.7 to 2.0.6
Warning: version conflict detected: org.clojure/tools.namespace version changes from 0.2.11 to 0.2.10
Warning: version conflict detected: com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core version changes from 2.1.1 to 2.3.2
```

I'm not quite understanding why sometimes the first version is lower than the other one and sometimes vice versa. It also looks that I cannot influence most of them. For example in my project I required `clj-time` in version `0.12.0`, so I guess the warning comes form a library, which itself requires clj-time in another version.

Is there way to fix them, or would I always use the `-q` flag in order to "suppress output from boot itself"? Would this maybe prevent other maybe more important output from being displayed?

Comment: did you try to use `-d` flag?

Comment: you mean to manually add the missing dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

File `/tmp/stackoverflow/boot.build`:

```
(set-env! :dependencies '[[clj-time "0.12.0"]
                          [joda-time "2.9.4"]])
```

In a terminal:

```
Borkdude@MBP /tmp/stackoverflow $ boot show -d
Warning: version conflict detected: joda-time version changes from 2.9.3 to 2.9.4
Warning: version conflict detected: joda-time version changes from 2.9.3 to 2.9.4
[clj-time "0.12.0"]
└── [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
[joda-time "2.9.4"]
Borkdude@MBP /tmp/stackoverflow $ boot show -p
Warning: version conflict detected: joda-time version changes from 2.9.3 to 2.9.4
Warning: version conflict detected: joda-time version changes from 2.9.3 to 2.9.4
[✔] joda-time
    ✔ 2.9.4
      joda-time
    ✘ 2.9.3
      clj-time
```

So, `boot show -d` will tell you the effective transitive dependency tree. `boot show -p` will give more detail about conflicts. Here it tells us that the dependency on `joda-time` pulls in `joda-time 2.9.4`, but it conflicts with `clj-time` wanting to pull in `joda-time 2.9.3`.

Suppose we didn't depend on `joda-time` directly but some other library `foo`, that depended on `joda-time 2.9.4`. We could then get rid of this warning by using an exclusion on `clj-time`: `[clj-time "0.12.0" :exclusions [joda-time]]` to get `2.9.4` in our project without a warning.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. boot show -d prints e.g. cljs-time only once in the tree: [clj-time "0.12.0"]..
Where's the warning taking the 0.8.0 from? + What do you mean by exclusions?